# Getting 401 when trying to access Spotify web API with access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, spotify, webapi

I am using Spotify strategy with passport Js for authentication. I then want to use the spotify-web-api-node wrapper library for calls to Spotify for the data. However using the access and refresh tokens gained from the authentication for the subsequent calls is not working out. I am getting a 401 - unauthorised when trying to make a call to Spotify for user specific data.

I tried instantiating the `SpotifyWebApiObject` with the refresh token and access token. Although I can see in the library it only needs the access token to make the calls. I have tried logging in and out to get new sets of the tokens as well.

```
passport.use(new SpotifyStrategy({
    clientID: keys.spotifyClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.spotifyClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/spotify/callback',
    proxy: true
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {


    const spotifyId = profile.id;
    const name = profile.displayName;
    const email = profile.emails[0].value;

    console.log(profile.id)
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ spotifyId: profile.id });

    if (existingUser) {
        let userCredentials = await UserCredential.findOne({ userId: spotifyId });

        if (!userCredentials) {
            return await new UserCredential({ userId: spotifyId, name, accessToken, refreshToken }).save();
        }
        console.log('always get existing user')
        userCredentials.accessToken = accessToken;
        userCredentials.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        return done(null, existingUser);
    }


    const user = await new User({ spotifyId }).save();
    await new UserCredential({ userId: spotifyId, name, accessToken, refreshToken }).save();

    done(null, user);
}));
```

Once they are stored in the db. I do a look up for the user and use the respective access and refresh tokens.

```
const getPlaylists = async (user) => {

    let spotifyData = await initiateSpotifyWebApi(user);

    spotifyData.getUserPlaylists(user.spotifyId).then((res) => {
        console.log('response is ===', res)
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));

}

async function initiateSpotifyWebApi(user) {

    const creds = await UserCredential.findOne({ userId: user.spotifyId });
    const apiCaller = setUpApiObj(creds.refreshToken, creds.accessToken);

    return apiCaller
}

function setUpApiObj(refreshTok, accessTok) {
       const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
        accessToken: accessTok,
        refreshToken: refreshTok
    });
    return spotifyApi;
}
```

```
getUserPlaylist()
```

returns an error

> { [WebapiError: Unauthorized] name: 'WebapiError', message: 'Unauthorized', statusCode: 401 }

Any idea why I cannot access the API using this library, the way I am trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to check. This is just what springs to mind. Correct me if I'm on the wrong track and I'll try to help further.

1. Check your **'scopes'** when you authenticate via Spotify. You need to have the correct scopes to perform different actions on the API. See here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/
2. If you get a 401, use your refresh token (I can see you're storing it) to automatically request, retrieve and overwrite your current AccessToken then perform the request again.

Comment: Scopes were the issue. Adding in `'playlist-read-collaborative'` scope at the authentication route got rid of this 401. Thanks @scgough.

Comment: Great. Glad it’s sorted.

Comment: Curious if anyone sees how this solution might apply to this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806773/spotify-api-error-401-permissions-missing-when-attempting-to-play-track