# Spotify API Error. 401 Permissions missing. When Attempting to Play Track

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, spotify

I am trying to play a track on my app using `spotify-web-api-node`

```
  const playSong = async () => {
    // Verify access token with
    console.log(spotifyApi.getAccessToken())

    setCurrentTrackId(track.track.id);
    setIsPlaying(true);
    spotifyApi
      .play({
        uris: [track.track.uri],
      })
      .then((d) => console.log("hi", d))
      .catch((e) => console.log("err", e));
  };
```

https://github.com/caseysiebel/spotify-clone/blob/main/components/Song.tsx#L19

When I fire off this call to `spotifyApi.play()`, I am getting this error back `WebapiRegularError: An error occurred while communicating with Spotify's Web API. Details: Permissions missing.` with error code 401.

I have the accessToken and refreshToken set in my app. I am able to log in and get data from the API such as user, playslist and track data. But when I try to play a track, it's says I don't have permission.

I thought this might have something to do with how I've set the `scopes` in the Spotify API, but they look correct to me.

```
const scopes = [
  "user-read-email",
  "playlist-read-private",
  "playlist-read-collaborative",
  "user-read-email",
  "streaming",
  "user-read-private",
  "user-library-read",
  "user-top-read",
  // "user-library-modify"
  "user-read-playback-state",
  "user-modify-playback-state",
  "user-read-currently-playing",
  "user-read-recently-played",
  "user-read-playback-state",
  "user-follow-read",
].join(",");
```

https://github.com/caseysiebel/spotify-clone/blob/main/lib/spotify.ts#L5

It seems like this has something to do with the `scopes` passed into the authorization `LOGIN_URL` but the `streaming` scope is definitely present and I can't see what the issue. It seems this way because certain API request work and others say they don't have permission.

Does anyone see what could be causing this issue with the missing persmisions issue and the Spotify API?

Comment: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/401-Permissions-missing-When-Attempting-to-Play-Track/m-p/5331047#M3962

Answer (score 0):

In `lib/spotify.ts` line 23 needed to be `scope: scopes,` not `scopes: scopes,`.

Actually using type checking probably would have been helpful here.

https://github.com/currenthandle/spotify-clone/commit/736108de1a1a132c43810d8415584f3be198609a#diff-b030a1ce426906990f8ed48fd8be76f54558b94141f4c811e679fef6661d396dR23

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your spotify.js file.
Here in clientId are you sure the name NEXT_PUBLICCLIENT_ID is right?
Shouldn't it be NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID.

```
    const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLICCLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECERT,
    });
```

Try and let me know if this work or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID` & `NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET` to `SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID` & `SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET` within your `[...nextauth].js`, `spotify.js`, & `.env` files.

Here's the NextAuth documentation with an example:
https://next-auth.js.org/providers/spotify